# Newton-Hensel method in number theory

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods

I am trying to find roots of the polynomial $f(x)=x^3  +1  \pmod {11^2}$ using the Newton-Hensel method.

By inspection, in mod 11, I see the only possible solution is -1. Plugging integers of this form into newton's formula I get: $(f(11k-1)/f'(11k-1) - 1$ for the new class of roots mod $11^2$ which finally simplifies to -1/(22k+1). Unless I made a dumb error, I don't see how I am any better off with this expression, I now have 121 integers to check if I want to solve for the roots of this function in this raised modular class explicitly.

Also, Any resources on this method would be appreciated, I haven't found much online.

Comment: Because 22 is divisible by 11, you have 22(k+11) = 22k (mod 121).  So you still only have 11 values of k to try.

Comment: sorry how does that follow? I am in mod $11^2$ at that point right?

Comment: The idea of Hensel's lemma is that it allows you to solve - no 'trying'- for the solution mod $p^{k+1}$,  if you know it already mod $p^k$. For instance there is no $f'(11k -1)$ needed, only $f'(-1)$. My answer below might help...

Comment: I am not familiar with this method,but there is another method :If p is an odd prime then multiplication mod $p^n $  (n>0) on the members of 1,..., $p^n-1$ that are not divisible by p, is a cyclic group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, $-1$ is the unique solution to $x^3 +1 \equiv 0\pmod {11} $, but not only by inspection, but - just a remark - also because the ration of any two possible solutions is  a third root of unity, and  $3 \not|\, 11-1$. At any rate, any solution $\pmod {11^2}$ is of the form $-1+ 11k$, where $k$ is unique  $\pmod {11}$.

Using "Taylor series,"
$$f( -1 + 11 k) \equiv f(-1) + 11 k f'(-1)  \pmod {11^2}.$$
Now, if you want the LHS $\equiv 0 \pmod {11^2}$ (i.e., 'doing' Hensel's lemma), one has (evaluating $f(-1)$ and $f'(-1)$) 
$$ 0 \equiv  0 + 11k 3 (-1)^2  \pmod {11^2}.$$
So $k \equiv 0\pmod {11}$, and $x=-1+ 11\cdot 0$ is the unique solution  to $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {11^2}$.

**Edit:** This is to illustrate/complete (and correct one of) the comments I made below. Suppose, instead of starting with $-1$, as you did, one had (maliciously) started with $10$, which is of course congruent to $-1$ modulo $11$. Then, $f(10)\equiv 0 \pmod {11}$. If one wanted to use Hensel's lemma to find a $k$ such that $f(10 +k 11)\equiv 0 \pmod {11^2}$ one would, as above, use "Taylor:"

$$f( 10 + 11 k) \equiv f(10) + 11 k f'(10)  \pmod {11^2}.$$
Since we want the LHS $\equiv 0 \pmod {11^2}$, one gets, after using on the RHS that $f(10)\equiv 33 \pmod {11^2}$ and $f'(10) = 3\cdot 10^2$, that 
$$ 0 \equiv  33 + 11\cdot k \cdot 3\cdot 10^2  \pmod {11^2}.\tag{*}$$
Dividing by $11$, one has to solve the equation
$$ 0 \equiv 3 + k\cdot 3\cdot 10^2  \pmod {11}.\tag{**}$$
Substituting $10\equiv -1$ above, one gets $k \equiv -1\pmod {11}$:  $x=10+ 11\cdot -1=-1$ is the unique solution  to $f(x)\equiv 0 \pmod {11^2}$ - which is the same as before.

**Note:** Hensel's algorithm  needs both that $f(a)\equiv 0 \pmod p $ and $f'(a) \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ (here with $p=11$, and $a\equiv -1\pmod {11}$):

The fact that $f(a)\equiv 0 \pmod {p}$ allows one to divide by $(*)$ by $p$.

The fact that $f'(a) \not\equiv 0 \pmod p$ allows one to divide  by $f'(a) \pmod p$ and solve for the (unique) $k \pmod p$  in $(**)$ to make $(*)$ hold true.

Comment: This is awesome (I had no idea taylor's theorem would come up in number theory, it really is an amazing theorem). Just a couple of questions:

1) Where does the error term go?
2) isn't the solution that k is congruent to zero mod $11^2$? I.e if -1 is a solution iff. k is congruent to 0 mod $11^2$?
3) I guess also, is this system surefire? And in what way is it different from Hensel's Lemma?

Comment: Well - the 'Taylor series' is a bit of whimsy here:  all I used above $$f(a + \delta) = f(a) + f'(a)\delta + O(\delta^2).$$ Also, it's a bit problematic to say Taylor series, because there are those factorials in the denominator in higher order terms - but I wanted you to see what was happening explicitly.

Comment: So why are we able to have the above identity? Also why do the order of delta squared terms disappear?

Also, can you explain the last line of your post?

Comment: OK - 1) the 'error term' is in mod $11^2$. 2) in the notation of my previous comment $\delta = 11k$ , and so $k$ is determined mod 11 3) this is Hensel's lemma - you want to solve for $k$  to make the congruence work at the next power of $11$. To see this, if by malice you had chosen, instead of $-1$ as your first guess,  $10 = -1+11$, then $f( 10) \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$ but $f(10) \equiv 32 \pmod {11^2}$. Hensel's lemma would have allowed you to 'improve' your initial (malicious) guess.

Comment: $x^3=-1$ isn't a great example for Hensel's lemma because it has an exact solution -1 in $\mathbb{Z}$ already, so once you start with -1, the later approximations can't get any better. It might be better to try an equation like $x^3 = 2$ instead so you can see the approximations get better at each stage.

Comment: @Ted is exactly right... But if you had started with $10$, or $21$, etc, repeated use of Hensel's lemma allows you to find a sequence which converges (in a suitable sense) to $-1$.  I also edited the last line of the answer to 'explain the last line of [my] post' which might have confused you.  I am off for the night - good luck!

Comment: Oh sorry! - I didn't answer your question about the identity: For $a$ fixed, then $(a+h)^n - a^n - na^{n-1}h$ is divisible by $h^2$ ('by algebra'). Therefore, for any polynomial $f(x)$, $f(a+h) - \{ f(a) + \delta f'(a) \}$ is divisible by $h^2$, because the corresponding identity holds for each $x^k$ term. OK?

Comment: How is 10 a malicious guess mod 11, isn't it the same as -1? Also, couldn't k be anything and the identity would still hold mod 11 (for the last line where you clarified). If you're already asleep, thanks anyway!

Ted: Ok, I'll give that example a shot.

Comment: Ah I was being so dumb about your solution Peter. I got it now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am glad you got it... Be that as it may, I updated the answer to illustrate using $10$ instead of $-1$ - please note that I screwed up in the comments: $f(10)\equiv 33 \pmod {11^2}$, and not $32$ - which was nuts as $f(10) \equiv 0 \pmod{11}$...  I woke up in the middle in the night racked with guilt.